# url could not give any response from json parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to post data on server but it could not give any response from the server side please check my code.

Does not gives any value for this url                                 NSString *urlLoc = @"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/bookappointment.php";

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&mobileno=%@&emailid=%@&dob=%@&password=%@&gender=%@&ref=%@&fbflag=0",goSignUpName,goSignUpMobile,goSignUpEmailId,goSignUpDOB,goSignUpPassword,goSignUpGender,goSignUpReferenceId] ;
NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLoc]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {

     if(data.length>0 && connectionError==nil)
     {


         responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"LOGIN Response ==> %@", responseData);

         if ([responseData intValue] == 1)
         {

             UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thanks" message:@"Registered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];

             for(id controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
             {
                 if([controller isKindOfClass : [ViewController class]]){ [self.navigationController popToViewController: controller animated: YES];
                     break;
                 }
             }



         }
         else if ([responseData intValue] == 2)
         {
             UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Already Reegistered" message:@"Please choose other Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
         }
         else if (responseData==NULL)
         {
             UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Not Book Try Again!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
         }


     }


 }];



}
```

Comment: problem not in your code , check once the URL is valid or not

Comment: Can you post the `connectionError` localizedDescription ?

Comment: http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/registration.php?name=qq&mobileno=123456789&emailid=hk@gmail&dob=2015-10-26&password=234&gender=MALE&ref=02&fbflag=0.This url give response when i hit on server

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is in your server code. It is not giving any response, while sending request from any source. You can verify using Postman(A Google Chrome Plugin)

UPDATE

OK, Server is expecting GET Request, but you are making a POST request

Please use below method.

```
-(void)sendToServerHandler:(NSString*)serviceURL showLoader:(BOOL)showLoader completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseData))completionBlock
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:serviceURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:600.0];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data,
                                               NSError *connectionError)
                {
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{

                            if(showLoader)
                            {
                                [appDelegate hideLoaderInstantaneously];
                            }
                               // handle response
                               if (connectionError)
                               {
                                   completionBlock(false, nil);
                                   return;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                    NSDictionary *parsedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                   if(parsedDictionary==nil)
                                   {
                                       completionBlock(false, nil);
                                       return;
                                   }

                                   completionBlock(true, parsedDictionary);
                               }
                           });
                       }];
```

}

It should give you appropriate response

Call it using

```
NSString *URL = @"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/registration.php?name=qq&mobileno=123456789&emailid=hk@gmail&dob=2015-10-26&password=234&gender=MALE&ref=02&fbflag=0";

[self sendToServerHandler:URL showLoader:showLoader completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseData)
{
    NSLog(@"response data  --> %@", reponse data);// RESPONSE FROM SERVER
}];
```

UPDATE

As you are using a http connection which is blocked by default by iOS 9 App Transport Security. I am hoping you would have added an exception for your URL. If not, below is the explained way.

> If you try to make HTTP requests with ATS enabled (using NSURLSession or libraries like AFNetworking), you’ll see errors like this:
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x12ed5bad0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x12ee495b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1004.)"
>   Or this:
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
>   Or this:
>   App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Here’s how to disable ATS entirely. Open Info.plist, and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

Follow the link for more details:
[Enable http connection in iOS 9](http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error)

Comment: http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/registration.php?name=qq&mobileno=123456789&emailid=hk@gmail&dob=2015-10-26&password=234&gender=MALE&ref=02&fbflag=0.This url give response when i hit on server

Comment: :-no one answer helpful for me..could any one help?

Comment: Can you please tell the issue or any error, you are receiving from above code. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is OK from the point of view of sending a HTTP call on iOS.
But it has a possible problem: you are creating the "requestString" parameter as a GET, but you are sending it as a POST body. Are you sure you want to do this?

Apart of this things seem to be fine.

Try setting "urlLoc" to a dummy value; for example "http://www.google.com" and you'll see that you get an error in the asynchronous callback.